# Quand utilise-t-on l'infinitif ou le participe passé dans un paragraphe ?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, temps-grammatical, participe-passé, infinitif

J'aimerais bien savoir quand on peut utiliser un verbe à l'infinitif ou an participe passé dans un paragraphe.

Je connais déjà une régle: on met le verbe à l'infinitif s'il y a une préposition comme *à*, *de*, *pour*, *sans*, *au*, ou après un verbe conjugué. J'aimerais bien savoir s'il y a d'autres régles ou bien des exceptions sur l'utilisation du verbe dans un paragraphe car je me trompe plusieurs fois surtout dans le cas qui requiert le participe passé, je le mets à l'infinitif.

Comment: Que signifie ici exactement "dans un paragraphe" ? As-tu un contexte précis ? S'agit-il d'une énumération, d'une liste de verbes ? Ou de l'usage de verbes dans une phrase quelconque ?

Comment: par exemple lorsque j'écris un résumé d'un livre je suis amené à écrire des paragraphes ou bien des phrases

Answer (score 2):

Il y a beaucoup d'emplois de l'infinitif, et moins des participes.

Voici des principes généraux qui peuvent s'appliquer:

**Infinitif**

- la présence de l'infinitif signifie l'acte porté par le verbe (nb: quelquefois, ce n'est pas un verbe d'action, mais d'état, mais le principe est le même). **On peut normalement le remplacer par un substantif ou un groupe nominal** .

**Le verbe en question n'est pas l'action principale: il existe un autre verbe rattaché au sujet qui exprime l'action principale.**

> Je veux manger. => je veux une pomme. Action principale = vouloir

**Il peut suivre toute préposition comme un groupe nominal.**

> Je pense à manger. => Je pense à une pomme. Action principale = penser.
>
> Je parle de manger. => Je parle d'une pomme.
>
> Je viens de manger. => Je viens de cette ville.
>
> Je viens pour parler. => je viens pour une conférence.

**Il peut suivre un semi-auxiliaire, jamais être ou avoir.**

Il y a toujours un parallèle avec un groupe nominal:

> Je veux manger. => Je veux une pomme. Action principale = vouloir.
>
> Je laisse tomber. => Je laisse l'affaire.
>
> Je pense (à) abandonner. => Je pense à l'abandon.
>
> Je dois arrêter. => Je dois un dû (sic).

Ou comme une proposition relative:

> Je vois couler le fleuve (je vois le fleuve couler) => Je vois le
> fleuve qui coule.
>
> Je crois marcher. => Je crois que je marche.

**Participe passé**

Il entre dans une construction avec un verbe auxiliaire **être ou avoir**, ou comme pseudo-adjectif.

**Il se rapporte directement au sujet sujet. Le verbe exprime bien l'action principale. L'auxiliaire est là pour préciser le temps.**

Il y a deux cas:

**avec le verbe avoir.**

Le verbe avoir ajoute une notion de passé. (passé composé, plus que parfait, ...)

**avec le verbe être: *Je suis monté*.**

- la construction exprime soit le passé (comme avec l'auxiliaire avoir), soit une construction passive (dans ce cas, le participe est similaire à un adjectif): c'est possible avec tous les verbes transitifs: *je suis démasqué, je suis ébloui.*
- dans ce cas, il s'accorde avec le **sujet**.
- et il peut souvent être remplacé par un adjectif: *je suis énervé*.

Un bon critère est donc de rechercher si on peut rattacher le verbe au verbe **être** et **lui trouver et le rattacher directement au sujet**.

Utilisation comme pseudo-adjectif:

> Pinocchio, avalé par la baleine, devisait tranquillement.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication juste une chose je suis pas d'accord avec vous sur le point du participe passé "Il entre dans une construction avec un verbe auxiliaire être ou avoir." on peut utiliser un participe passe sans avoir un verbe auxiliaire être ou avoir

Comment: @downloaddowload . Oui, utilisé comme pseudo-adjectif. J'ai rajouté ce cas dans ma réponse.

Comment: ok merci pour la réponse même si je n'ai pas encore trouvé la bonne réponse que je cherche

Answer (score 0):

Je ne sais pas si c'est ce que tu cherches mais pour les verbes du premier groupe (manger) tu remplaces par un verbe du troisième (mordre).

*Je voudrai manger une pomme* -> *Je voudrai mordre une pomme* Infinitif

*J'ai mangé une pomme* -> *J'ai mordu une pomme* Participe passé

Comment: Bah ici pour le cas d'un verbe manger et pour les autres verbes ? je pense que je vais changer le titre et je vais mettre Quand on utilise l'infinitif ou participe passé dans un paragraphe

Comment: C'est valable pour tout les verbes du premier groupe

Comment: Cette règle n'est utile que pour quelqu'un parlant couramment français et qui remarquera que un infinitif ou un participe passé du troisième groupe sonne bon ou faux. Pour le cas d'un étranger, cela ne sera pas évident du tout.