# « Marcher » ou « marché » (infinitif ou participe passé)

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, participe-passé, infinitif

J'ai une ambiguïté entre mettre verbe à l'infinitif ou au participe passé en prenant par exemple cette phrase:

> Je pense que logiciel ça va marché.

ou bien

> Je pense que logiciel ça va marcher.

Quelle phrase est juste ? et pourquoi ? J'aimerais aussi savoir la règle pour choisir entre l'infinitif et le participe passé ?

Comment: if there is no auxiliary (*avoir* / *être*), there is very few chances to be a *participe passé*

Comment: question similaire là: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/quand-on-utilise-t-on-linfinitif-ou-le-participe-pass%C3%A9-dans-un-paragraphe/17351#17351

Answer (score 2):

Tu peux utiliser l'une des deux phrases "Je pense que le logiciel va marcher" ou bien "Je pense que cela/ça va marcher" où cela/ça fait référence au logiciel.

Tu dois utiliser marcher à l'infinitif puisque tu as deux verbes (*aller* et *marcher*) qui se suivent donc le deuxième doit être impérativement à l'infinitif (*marcher*).

Comment: Dans _j'ai marché_, n'ai-je pas deux verbes qui se suivent ? Pourquoi est-ce différent ?

Comment: "ai" est l’auxiliaire "avoir". "j'ai marché" est la conjugaison du verbe "marcher" à la première personne du singulier au passé composé.

Comment: @Random C'est une question rhétorique, mon but est qu'on distingue, dans la réponse, pour le bénéfice des apprenants. Les commentaires ne sont pas indexés. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

Petit truc pour choisir entre infinitif et participe passé : remplacer ton verbe par un autre verbe qui se termine par -ir (partir, finir, devenir…) et de tester infinitif et participe passé. Cela permet de constater à l'oreille la bonne solution :

> Je pense que le logiciel va fini.

Non, ça ne paraît pas correct

> Je pense que le logiciel va finir

Voilà qui paraît plus correct, même si cela n'a pas de sens.

Cette logique fonctionne avec des francophones de langue maternelle. Je ne sais pas si cela fonctionnerait avec des personnes dont le français est une langue secondaire.

Comment: Je pense que le feeling avec un autre verbe sera compliqué pour les non natifs. C'est plus dur de se dire "ça sonne faux" dans une langue étrangère...